# Время, через которое может писать новый участник чата

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу простого бота для телеграм чата на pyTelegramBotAPI.

Суть бота заключается в том, чтобы он давал вступившим в чат участникам мут на n-ое количество времени. Облазил много сайтов, но толком не нашел команд для реализации данного. Сталкивался кто с таким?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот метод используйте, чтобы изменить разрешения пользователя в чате (там же разрешение на отправку сообщений) https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#restrictchatmember
Класс разрешений - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatpermissions